# How to map or use local files in Gradle Managed Device?

Tags: android, gradle, emulation, virtual

I use a virtual Gradle-managed device ([link](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/gradle-managed-devices)) to create a virtual device in CI/CD workflow on GitHub. This does work well and I can run instrumented tests using with virtual device. The virtual device is created automatically and then close after tests.

My issue is that I need to use local files in the tests.

- Is there an option to map local files/folders into the virtual device?
- May be there is a specific path I can use in virtual device to access local files?

Here is an example of virtual device specification.

```
android {
    testOptions {
        managedDevices {
            localDevices {
                pixel2api30 {
                    // Use device profiles you typically see in Android Studio.
                    device = "Pixel 2"
                    // Use only API levels 27 and higher.
                    apiLevel = 30
                    // To include Google services, use "google".
                    systemImageSource = "aosp"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In see several possible solutions:

- There should be an option how to do this using virtual managed devices, but it's not enough documentation. I checked API of [ManagedVirtualDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/8.4/com/android/build/api/dsl/ManagedVirtualDevice) and [TestOptions](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/8.4/com/android/build/api/dsl/TestOptions), didn't find suitable solution.
- The emulator can be created manually without usage of virtual Gradle-managed device. Then using adb files can be pushed to the emulator. Not an easy, but possible case.
- Create Custom Test Lab to support h/w device with prepared files on the device.

Thank you.